# Is there a way to select one value over different post types with ACF?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if the following is possible in WordPress.

I have a custom post type named `Videos`. Every video that will be created will be displayed on the video page. One of the videos will be set as the hero video and will be bigger on the page.

I was wondering if there is a way to select one hero image and place it in the bigger frame of the site? The user should select one of the created videos.

I use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to manage the pages and create extra options for the custom post type.

Is there a way to use something like a true/false statement that will update on each video page backend? So, if I have 3 videos and I set video 2 to `true`, the other ones will be `false`. If I than set video 3 to `true`, video 2 will be automatically set to `false`, because only one true is possible.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Here what I would do: create a new setting field of type Relationnal Post Object, not on the video post but on the page that display all videos, to select the featured video to display.

Comment: Another alternative - although not as nice, user experience wise - is to just query one video that is set to `true` and ignore the others. Advise the user not to set more than one to `true`, otherwise only the first one that is returned in the query will be used anyway (the other solutions are better, I just offer this as an alternative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Post Object on the page template that is used to display the videos. More information can be found here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

The selected post can then be shown in the hero and there is no need to have an 'auto-updating' option for each individual video.